# unable to remove the space from list object

Tags: python, python-2.7

am trying the below scenerios but unable to get the soluction.

```
('bgp', ['[11.1.2.1, 11.1.2.2]'])
<type 'list'>
```

how do we get as below and type should be list, there should be no space after , and the output should be as below in list format.

Need expected output as below in in list format

```
y = ['11.1.2.1','11.1.2.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
initial = ('bgp', ['[11.1.2.1, 11.1.2.2]'])
result = (initial[1][0][1:-1]).split(", ")

print result
```

`result` would equal `['11.1.2.1', '11.1.2.2']` which is a list of strings.

When lists are returned the space is ignored. In order to have what you described, a list with no spaces, it would need to be a string object.

Comment: Thanks you so much Andrew.. Appreciate it.. This is what i was looking for .. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, if you found the answer helpful please considering marking it as correct. Thanks!